# Error using freeze_graph.py with Keras model converted to estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am testing building a model in Keras and then turning it into some Tensorflow format so that I can run predictions in the Tensorflow C++ API. I'm adapting from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183). I am testing on the MNIST dataset and have built my model in Keras:

```
inpt = keras.layers.Input(shape = (28,28,1), name = "input_node")
x = keras.layers.Convolution2D(16, 2, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(inpt)
x = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Convolution2D(32, 2, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2)(x)

x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)

output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation  = 'softmax', name = "output_node")(x)

model = keras.models.Model(inpt,output)

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0001), loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

and then used the `model_to_estimator` function:

```
estimator_model = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model = model, model_dir = './TF_MNIST')
```

This works well, and I can train using:

```
estimator_model.train(input_fn = input_function(X_train,y_train,True))
```

However, I'm trying to use [freeze_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) as follows:

```
checkpoint_state_name = "model.ckpt-21001.index"
input_graph_name = "graph.pbtxt"
output_graph_name = "output_graph.pb"

input_graph_path = os.path.join('./TF_MNIST', input_graph_name)
input_saver_def_path = ""
input_binary = False
input_checkpoint_path = os.path.join('./TF_MNIST', checkpoint_state_name)

output_node_names = "output_node" 
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
output_graph_path = os.path.join('./TF_MNIST', output_graph_name)
clear_devices = False

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path,
                      input_binary, input_checkpoint_path,
                      output_node_names, restore_op_name,
                      filename_tensor_name, output_graph_path,
                      clear_devices, initializer_nodes = "input_node")
```

where I have chosen then name `output_graph.pb` for the destination of the generated freeze_graph.

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-215edbaaf017> in <module>()
      3  output_node_names, restore_op_name,
      4  filename_tensor_name, output_graph_path,
----> 5  clear_devices, initializer_nodes = "input_node")

ValueError: No variables to save
```

In the example in the tutorial, there is no input argument `initializer_nodes` so I assumed it was the name of the input node. Additionally, when I use checkpoint files that are not `.index` files, it gives a `Data loss` warning, saying that the data is not in the right format.

#### Questions:

1. How can I fix this error?
2. Why is the `.index` checkpoint file the right one to use (if, indeed it is correct)?
3. The tutorial has a `input_graph.pb` graph, whereas mine is a `.pbtxt`, why is that?
4. Can I introduce `tf.Session()` into my Keras model to store and print accuracy scores, as currently these are not being printed in training, nor are they being stored in the checkpoint file being read by TensorBoard.

Any help on any of these questions would be much appreciated.